# Async Web handler not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, ashx

I try to migrate the custom web handler from Webforms project to MVC. It worked fine back there and called async ProcessRequest.

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    ...
    public async void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    ...
```

However, when I run it in my MVC project ( /Content/MyHandler.ashx ), I get following error:

*An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.*

I tried making ProcessRequest synchronous (I removed "async" in method definition and changed all the async calls from `await Method()` to `Method().Result`, but it didn't help, the server just loads the page forever.
I also tried replacing `IHttpHandler` with `IHttpAsyncHandler`, but it didn't work.
I also tried moving handler file in the root and in the custom folder, the result is the same.
Please help!

Comment: Have you considered just using a controller? Seems simpler to me..

Comment: Nope, because it seemed oposite of simpler to me, I wanted to use the solution I already have (mind you, it's a relatively big handler)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the abstract [HttpTaskAsyncHandler](https://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi0-IS1hK_MAhXjFZoKHeqHDBsQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.httptaskasynchandler(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFJvt2If9MdH3iqzaW-TOiol6xmZw&cad=rja) class.

```
public class MyHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
{
    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it before but I've got error "Not all code paths return value" because I use "return;" to break.

Comment: Your solution (almost) worked, I just needed to change method to *public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync*

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you, let me edit my answer so other people don't   get confused.

Comment: This is a good solution, just need to point out that there is a .NET 4.5 prerequisite to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the method declaration from:

```
public async void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

to

```
public async Task ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: 'MyHandler' does not implement interface member 'IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext)'. 'MyHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext)' cannot implement 'IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'void'.

Comment: You were close, see the solution above.

Comment: Yes. The "override" is a different story because the compiler will complain anyways and that should be an easy fix in your end. Great that you were able to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

So far I've managed to solve it by converting ashx to regular web form (aspx) and placing Async="true" in the Page directive.
However if there are still solutions with webhandler, I would prefer it...

EDIT:
After all, partially the solution proposed by Kerim Emurla worked, but I just needed to change one bit:
public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync